WP save_post_{$post->post_type} with ACF custom post type leads to infinite loop
I'm using ACF Pro to easily register a custom post type for an internal use purpose (no frontend). Every feature is disabled (content, title, slug, ...) as I need to set a UUID as the post_title and post_name, and every other bit of data is handled by ACF.
I used the save_post_{$post->post_type} hook, with a priority of 25, in order to hook into the post save and format the title to a UUIDv4 string, and came with the code below :
<?php 
// ...
public function wprc_set_post_title_to_uuid4($post_id)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

    if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) return;

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ($post_type != 'wprc_machinery_fleet') return;

    remove_action('save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post', 10);
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_title' => uuidv4()));
    add_action('save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post', 10);
}
add_action('save_post', array($this, 'wprc_set_post_title_to_uuid4'), 10);


I'm now turning mad not being able to figure out why I trigger an infinite loop upon post creation (add new) and post update (edit).
As soon as I hit the Add New button, a post is effectively created in the DB with the auto-draft status, but instantly loops:  post_title is constantly updated (checked with PHPMyAdmin). Same effect runs on an existing post update.
I checked so many times, did use the remove_action() and add_action() hooks, but this seems ignored ...
What am I doing wrong here ?
Is there a way to achieve this by other means ?
I imagined creating a text field with ACF and dynamically inserting a UUID in it and using this to edit my post title, but I would face the same issue?
EDIT: Solved.
For anyone looking, corrected code below (function names and callback format):
<?php 
// ...
public function wprc_set_post_title_to_uuid4($post_id)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

    if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) return;

    remove_action('save_post_wprc_machinery_fleet', array($this, 'wprc_set_post_title_to_uuid4'), 10);
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_title' => uuidv4()));
    add_action('save_post_wprc_machinery_fleet', array($this, 'wprc_set_post_title_to_uuid4'), 10);
}
add_action('save_post_wprc_machinery_fleet', array($this, 'wprc_set_post_title_to_uuid4'), 10);



What does wpse51363_save_post and uuidv4() do? You can use add_action('save_post_ wprc_machinery_fleet'.
Looks like your function that fires on save post is calling update_post which (iirc) calls save_post again, hence the looping

What is this? wpse51363_save_post

Oh. You're doing this? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51364/57589. You need to change the callback to match your function.

Yeah, actually i did get the code from there, and did chang it in my code. but when cleaning up for posting here, it mixed up. However, found the culprit: myself...
Did not change the code to work in a Class environment, to remove_action('...', array($this', '...'), 20); ...

Looks like you're removing the incorrect function name. Try this:
<?php

public function wprc_set_post_title_to_uuid4($post_id)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

    if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) return;

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ($post_type != 'wprc_machinery_fleet') return;

    remove_action('save_post', array( $this, 'wprc_set_post_title_to_uuid4' ), 10);
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_title' => uuidv4()));
    add_action('save_post', array( $this, 'wprc_set_post_title_to_uuid4' ), 10);
}
add_action('save_post', array($this, 'wprc_set_post_title_to_uuid4'), 10);


Thanks. See my comment below the function nams was correct in the code, but I did not change the remove and add hooks to the ($this, 'callback') format ...
